# understanding probability calculation for naive bayes

Tags: math, statistics, document-classification

With the naive bayes text classification technique, you typically count words in training data and calculate p(label | document) where the document is a string of words?

for text classification, why can't we compute P(label | word1, word2, etc) directly to predict the label? (i.e. why do we need to use bayes theorem)

Given the documents, we have full data... seems should be able to calculate p(label and w1 and w2 ) / p(w1 and w2) directly?

I realize that the training set is not ground truth. Does calculating it with Bayes theorem solve that problem? If so, how? Can you show how the math works?

Answer (score 2):

Bayes uses prior information from your training set and data to estimate posteriori propability.

I think "we have full data" would be a frequentist point of view.

Bayes is an improvement over frequentist approaches for a lot of reasons, but one of them is that it allows you to improve your posteriori using past information.

I'd recommend reading [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis - A Tutorial Using R and BUGS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123814855).  It's a terrific book on a very important topic.  Bayes has won the war - best to learn it thoroughly.

Comment: Can you show how the math for calculating the probabilities with bayes theorem will give you a better result? Is there a tutorial that explains that better?

Comment: Bayes is the scientific method in math.  When your prior information is in question, you can get different posterior results.  When you get more information, and priors converge to an agreed upon value, your posterior values become more reliable.  You don't need math to tell you that better past information gives you a better future result.  Read the citation I gave.

Comment: My understanding of why it's called "Bayes" is just that it uses Bayes' theorem - nothing to do with whether a bayesian or a frequentist approach is preferred. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: If you're using Bayes, you prefer that approach.  "We have full data" suggests to me that you want to draw your conclusions only from the data, without using priors.  That's a frequentist approach.  The book that I cited will do a much, much better job than I'm willing or able to do on a forum.

Comment: duffymo is correct here, 'naive Bayes' is a special case of Bayesian methods in which you make the (sweeping and almost always unreasonable) assumption that all the things you care about are independent. That's virtually *never* true in real life, but it can lead to computationally parsimonious results that work well in practice. It definitely *does* entail a distinction from less rigorous frequentist methods, but because of the specific assumption of naive Bayes, it resembles frequentist methods and many lazy practitioners don't make the distinction.

Comment: Two really useful links for better understanding this are: [Wagenmakers et al book chapter on differences between Bayesian and frequentist approaches](http://commonsenseatheism.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Wagenmakers-et-al-Bayesian-versus-frequentist-inference.pdf) and [Zhang's paper on the paradoxical optimality of naive Bayes](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-dm/s11/SECURE/Optimality_of_Naive_Bayes.pdf). Note: I grabbed these links from the first convenient search sources. I'm not trying to endorse the linked websites or anything.

Comment: Very nice citations, EMS.  Thank you for posting them.

Comment: I guess you are saying that `X _|_ Y | Z` is a non-frequentist statement. Doesn't make sense to me, but I'm no expert so I'll trust you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  I'm no expert either, so I'd recommend that you keep digging on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The name "Naive Bayes" is kind of misleading because it's not really that remarkable that you're calculating the values via Bayes' theorem. As you point out, Bayes' theorem is derived from the standard definition of conditional probability, so we can prove that the answer given via Bayes' theorem is identical to the one calculated normally.

The insight (or false assumption, depending on your point of view) is that word frequencies are often indpendent given the document's label. Because of this `P(w_1, ..., w_n | label)` is easy to calculate: `P(w_1, ..., w_n | label) = P(w_1 | label) * ... * P(w_n | label)`.

But of course we don't care about `P(w_1, ..., w_n | label)`, we want `P(label | w_1, ..., w_n)`. So we need to use Bayes' theorem, hence the name.

By doing it this way, we can embed our knowledge about words' independencies to make better predictions. If we just did the raw calculation, there would be no way of encoding our knowledge about independence.

(This is true in general of Bayes nets, not just Naive Bayes - the benefit is that you can encode your prior knowledge about relationships between variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Having researched, asked a few people, and thought about it. The reason why you don't compute:

p(label | W1 = 1, W2 = 2 etc) directly

is because it would be computationally difficult since you'd need to keep an index of bigrams, trigrams, etc. And even then you would need a clever way to deal with the words that appear zero times in your index.

Using Bayes is a nice way to get around the problem, but you do need to make the conditional independence assumption.

You can also get the formula into a different form where the words is still on the right hand side. Below is the math starting with the numerator from using the bayes formula:

p(w1 | c ) * p (w2 | c) ... * p(c)

this can be decomposed to

p(c | w1) * p(w1) / p(c)   *  p(c | w2) * p(w2) / p(c) ... p(c | Wn) * p(Wn) / p(c) * p(c)

which simplifies to

p(c | w1) ... p(c | Wn)*p(c)^-(n-1)*p(w1)....p(Wn)